Пунктуация в предложении с предлогом «несмотря на»
Да и сегодня он все тот же, несмотря на три десятка лет, мы не потеряли интерес друг к другу.

• Вот что имеется в справочнике Розенталя (Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными, п. 2):

Оборот с предложным сочетанием несмотря на как правило, [sic] обособляется: Несмотря на запрет врачей, он поехал в далёкую таёжную экспедицию. Однако при тесной смысловой связи с господствующим словом, после которого он находится, оборот этот не обособляется: Явился дежурный администратор, вызванный несмотря на поздний час; Он это сделал несмотря на запрет матери.

• А вот что — в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина (Знаки препинания при обособленных обстоятельствах, § 75):

Обстоятельственные члены предложения, имеющие в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания (...несмотря на... ), обособляются при подчеркивании их смысла: <...> Любопытных, несмотря на кажущуюся тишину и безлюдье поселка, собралось немало (Степ.)...
Оборот со словами несмотря на может не обособляться только в случае, если он стоит непосредственно после глагола: Он это сделал несмотря на запрет врачей (ср.: Несмотря на запрет врачей, он это сделал).

✦ А вот мое пунктуационное решение:
первую запятую я бы заменила на тире (потому что нужна приличная пауза), а вторую бы оставила (тут тоже нужна подчеркивающая пауза, но — поменьше).
Да и сегодня он все тот же — несмотря на три десятка лет, мы не потеряли интерес друг к другу.

Спасибо! А почему не точка с запятой вместо тире? Там ведь нет поясняющего значения, а просто пауза.

@Людмила Петрикова  Как раз хотела сказать, что лучше точка с запятой. Но у меня лучше по интонации, паузы у знаков тоже разные, слышится по-другому. Здесь присоединительные отношения, оба знака подходят.  Но для тире  нужно уточнять характер присоединения, связь более тесная, а пояснения здесь действительно нет. А вот для точки с запятой ничего этого не нужно: знак ближе к точке, только пауза меньше. Одна мысль продолжает другую, чувствуется характер размышления.

Это БСП, там всегда есть выбор между знаками. Запятая не подойдёт,  так как нужно разделить предложение на две части,  а тире обозначает взаимообусловленность, которой здесь нет.
